# How to use nscala-time parse string with specific format

Tags: scala, datetime

I find this time library for Scala, it is a wrapper of Joda Time. But I can't find out a way to parse a String into DateTime objects using that library.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
DateTime.xxx
```

After importing that library, the DateTime doesn't have a method `parse`, which takes a Date String and a specific DateTimeFormatter as the arguments, and returns a DateTime object.

Comment: I am not sure if nscala-time supports this. You can parse a string to using `com.github.nscala_time.time.RichString`, but you can't specify the format. You may have to resort to joda time: `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime(time)`

Comment: @KuluLimpa Yes, it seems that the com.github.nscala_time.time.RichString does not support specifying format. So does it mean there is no way to parse specific formatted date string into a datetime object and then apply  those additional methods provided by nscala_time?

Comment: You can use the way provided by @KuluLimpa and then still use the additional methods provided by nscala-time. These methods are available on the resulting ordinary DateTime object via implicit conversion to nscala-time's RichDateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._` use 'DataTime' as [alias](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/Imports.scala#L41) to '[StaticDateTime](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticDateTime.scala)'.
So you can do one of the following:

1. use the [DateTimeFormat](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/StaticDateTimeFormat.scala). e.g.:  `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("DD:HH").parseDateTime("11:22")`
2. import the org.joda.time.DateTime after the nscala_time imports (and lose the StaticDateTime)
3. use full name: `org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(...)`
4. import one of them with different name:

   ```
   import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
   import org.joda.time.{DateTime=>JodaDateTime}
   JodaDateTime.parse(...)
   ```

Comment: So does that mean that if I want to parse specific format date time, then what actually I get is an instance of org.joda.time.DateTime, and all the additional functionality provided by nscala_time are not available?

Comment: No. you always use JadaTime classes. The lib mostly wrapers implicit classes around JadaTime classes. So if you do something like `DateTime.now + 5.seconds` the result is '**org.joda.time.DateTime** = 2014-10-04T17:42:56.355+03:00'